# Is there possible to restart gunicorn by writing a script inside a python-django application? If yes, how should this script look like?

Tags: python, django, nginx, server, gunicorn

Sometimes the server of my website crashes and/or gets really slow, usually from multiple API processes, thread calls that last really long, and multiple workers/users performing different activities.

After getting a 502 bad gateway, I usually restart the gunicorn.

In my understanding, the reason for the 502 Error means that the Nginx is having trouble connecting to the Gunicorn process.

The solution I have so far is by manually login into the server, and performing `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`, and I manually kill those processes based on their pids.

However I would like to know if there is any way of restarting gunicorn automatically by using some sort of script, and repeat the process once or twice a week?

Comment: Do you have many long running calls? Not the best scenario for a web app. But unicorn has many setting to tune. You can configure it to kill hanging workers or use an other worker class. From my experience the work class "gevent" performs much better when you have long running tasks.

Comment: Yes, I do. Usually one API call takes for example (200 items / hour); assuming that if I have only 200 items (which rarely is the case); the results will take 1 hour to be received. At the same time I have other workers who run a different API call of magnitude of (500,000 items / hour). And the number of workers that perform these API calls sometimes changes and varies; and can be bigger then 4/day. On top of those workers, I have daily uses of my-application (which does not involve api calls), but accesses internal-db with data, very frequently.

Comment: However, thank you for the reply, I will look into the 'gevent'.